# Unique pointer to template interface

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

For sake of simplicity I reduced my problem to simple example. I have base class:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
    virtual T getParameter(T&) = 0;
};
```

and derived class that returns its object using factory method:

```
template<typename T>
class Der : public Base<T> {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Der> getInstance() {
        return std::make_unique<Der<std::string>>();
    }
    T getParameter(T& param) override {
        return param;
    }
};
```

Now I would like to pass objects of derived class using unique_ptr that holds interface, i.e:

```
template<typename T>
void someFun(std::unique_ptr<Base<T>>&& ptr) {
//do sth with ptr
}
```

by calling:

```
someFun(Der<std::string>::getInstance());
```

Error:

```
test.cpp:26:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘someFun(std::unique_ptr<Der<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::default_delete<Der<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >)’
     someFun(Der<std::string>::getInstance());
                                            ^
test.cpp:21:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void someFun(std::unique_ptr<Base<T> >&&)
 void someFun(std::unique_ptr<Base<T>>&& ptr) {
      ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:21:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:26:44: note:   mismatched types ‘Base<T>’ and ‘Der<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’
     someFun(Der<std::string>::getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to tackle this is to make an alias of `T` in `Base`, template on the derived type, and use that instead of relying on template deduction.

You can still enforce the inheritance from `Base` by using `std::is_base_of<>` if you are afraid of duck-typing in something unrelated by accident.

```
#include <memory>
#include <typer_traits>

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    using param_t = T;
    virtual T getParameter(T&) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Der : public Base<T> {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Der> getInstance() {
        return std::make_unique<Der<std::string>>();
    }
    T getParameter(T& param) override {
        return param;
    }
};

template<typename DerivT>
void someFun(std::unique_ptr<DerivT> deriv_ptr) {
    using T = typename DerivT::param_t;
    // Just to be safe
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base<T>, DerivT>::value, "");

    // If you REALLY care about only having a base pointer:
    std::unique_ptr<Base<T>> ptr(deriv_ptr.release());    

    //do stuff.
}

void foo() {
    someFun(Der<std::string>::getInstance());
}
```

You would also be able to finaggle something with `enable_if` if you really wanted to handle different overloads of `someFun()`. However, I find the `static_assert()` way a lot cleaner, so I would use that unless necessary.

Comment: You just changed the whole parameter to T, I know about that, but I need Base<T>>

Comment: @user3655463 in the context of someFun(), `T` **was** actually `Derived<param_t>`, I can understand the confusion, I have fixed the example

Answer (score 0):

First time I will answer my own, question, the solution is return unique ptr to Base not Derived class:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Base<T>> getInstance() {
    return std::make_unique<Der<std::string>>();
}
```

previously I returned `static std::unique_ptr<Der>` and compiler assumed that I don't want to ref my object using interface. Maybe it will help anybody having the same issue.